# "Scanner cannot be resolved to a type" how can i fix it?

Tags: java

I am taking an online course to learn java and currently we are learning "Getting User Input". this is what ive started with so far...

```
public class mama {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Scanner input;
    }
}
```

however it keeps saying "Scanner input;"

what do i do?

Comment: You may look closer in the tutorial, first lines should have an "import" statement with the actual import of the Scanner class.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class mama{
 public static void main(String[] args) {

 Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in); 
 System.out.print("Enter input value ");  
 int a = sc.nextInt();  
   }
}
```

you can get input from the user just like this in your main function.

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned any value to the scanner variable, the first step to using a scanner is importing the library, then assigning the scanner a variable like "sc" or "keyboard" (which I use), then assign *something* the scanner variable.

**Step by step breakdown:**

You are missing:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

This is the first step, *always remember*

Then do this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Lastly, assign the "sc" to something, either a string or Int variables.

For example:

```
int number = sc.nextInt();
```

or:

```
String x = sc.next();
```

Note: You need to understand what the scanner variables are for every type of variable you assign for example string or Int.

For String it is:

```
sc.next();
```

For Int:

```
sc.nextInt();
```

Same goes for double, float...etc, just change the *Int* to what you want

In the end, your code should look something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class mama {
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter desired input");
    int input = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```